How to modify style of MaterialDataPicker?
I try to modify style of MaterialDataPicker which is showed in attached figure.
I using xml style file, but every modifies that I try doesn't work.

This is my xml style, when I set simple style to two element of MaterialDataPicker:
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ProvaJava" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <!-- Tema personalizzato per MaterialDatePicker -->
    <style name="CustomMaterialDatePickerTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/CustomCalendarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomCalendarTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/CustomCalendarHeaderTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarDay">@style/CustomCalendarDayTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomCalendarHeaderTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/nunito</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/apptext</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomCalendarDayTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/nunito</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    </style>


</resources>

What's wrong?
